# Karate Tests Run slow when calling many other feature files from one scenario

Tags: karate

I have a test flow with alot of inter dependencies, therefore I have about 10 `call read()` calls in one scenario.
After 3-4 `call read()` the tests starts to slow down(sometime even staying stuck for 15 minutes). And sometime even face `Java heap space` error.

Is ther any way to resolve this ?

I have so many calls in one scenario due to interdependencies(one call depending on the previous one). Is there any way to make sure that I distribute the tests across scenarios but if one scenario fails in feature file, other scenarios should not run.

Comment: there is no way to help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - for examples of people who have done this, see: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1675 - and make sure that you are using the latest version 1.2.0.RC3 first

Comment: Updating the version fixed the issue. I was a bit skeptical to use a RC version..but it looks good. thanks!